# IPv6 AAAA record not resolving for sub domain

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, dns-zone

Hi have one domain lets say example.in, i have been using one of its subdomain for my application purpose xyz.example.in, i have following NS record for main domain and sub domain :

```
example.in  NS      ns54.jinfo.net
example.in  NS      ns51.jinfo.net
example.in  NS      ns52.jinfo.net
example.in  NS      ns53.jinfo.net

xyz.example.in  NS      ns1.xyz.example.in
xyz.example.in  NS      ns2.xyz.example.in
xyz.example.in  NS      ns3.xyz.example.in
xyz.example.in  NS      ns4.xyz.example.in
xyz.example.in  NS      ns5.xyz.example.in
```

NS1,NS2,NS3 are for IPV4 and NS4,NS5 are for IPV6

I have added following A records for main and subdomain :

```
example.in  A       192.0.2.0     
www.example.in A    192.0.2.0
ns1.xyz.example.in   A  192.0.2.1
ns2.xyz.example.in   A  192.0.2.2
ns3.xyz.example.in   A  192.0.2.3
```

When i am checking A record for sub domain xyz.example.in, it is resolving ip : 192.0.2.0  though i have not added A record for sub domain xyz.example.in, but it is resolving , which is ok.

I have added following IPV6 AAAA record for main and subdomain :

```
www.example.in      AAAA        2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
example.in        AAAA      2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
ns4.xyz.example.in AAAA 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
ns5.xyz.example.in AAAA 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002
```

Now here IPV6 AAAA records are resolving for main domain example.in with 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 but not resolving for subdomain xyz.example.in.

It is really strange, A record for sub domain is resolving but AAAA record are not resolving.

can anyone help me with this, i need to resolve my domain over IPV6.

Comment: `but it is resolving , which is ok` is it? I'd be curious as to HOW this happens with the configuration you've shown

Comment: Yes, for xyz.example.in it is resolving ip of main domain example.in- 1.1.1.1, but same is not working for AAAA records

Comment: hang on ... you have separate nameservers for IPv4 vs IPv6? and they are configured differently? I thought the idea of multiple name servers was redundancy in case one or more fail ... not for them to return different information

Comment: Also, you have AAAA records for `5.5.5.5` which is IPv4? Debugging DNS problems is impossible with sketchy information. Please edit your question to include the actual domain and the actual records. This is DNS so they are public anyway, but enables others to test what is actually happening.

Comment: @EsaJokinen, ok i have added actual domain and ip as per your suggestion, can you gide to resolve issue ?

Answer (score 3):

The `ns51.jinfo.net` etc. nameservers delegates the control of `mbanking.kalupurbank.in` to the nameservers with glue records.

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 38400  IN      NS      ns5.mbanking.kalupurbank.in.
mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 38400  IN      NS      ns4.mbanking.kalupurbank.in.
mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 38400  IN      NS      ns3.mbanking.kalupurbank.in.
mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 38400  IN      NS      ns2.mbanking.kalupurbank.in.
mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 38400  IN      NS      ns1.mbanking.kalupurbank.in.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 7200 IN    A       14.141.120.244
ns5.mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 28800 IN   AAAA    2001:df2:d100::156
ns4.mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 28800 IN   AAAA    2001:df2:d100::4
ns3.mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 7200 IN    A       14.141.120.236
ns2.mbanking.kalupurbank.in. 7200 IN    A       115.249.195.122
```

However,

- The IPv4 nameservers `14.141.120.244`, `14.141.120.236` & `115.249.195.122` are not *authoritative* for this zone.

  ```
  ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
  ```
- The IPv6 nameservers `2001:df2:d100::156` & `2001:df2:d100::4` are not responding at all.

  ```
  ;; communications error to 2001:df2:d100::156#53: timed out
  ```

**You do not need to have separate name servers for the subdomains.** Frankly, if you do not understand any of DNS, you should not try to implement DNS on your own. Simply add the `mbanking.kalupurbank.in` `A` & `AAAA` records directly to the zone at the `jinfo.net` nameservers and let them handle this for you.

Comment: my ip keeps changing, so each time i have to update A and AAAA record manually, so i want domain to be pointed to ip which is up automatically, DNS is not my area just filling in gap, by taking help of seniors like you

Comment: Are you seriously running mobile banking services on a dynamic IP address?

Comment: Certainly succeeds at the "looked like a legitimate url for my bank".

Answer (score 1):

Each of your name servers is authoritative for the domain it serves. If each one can resolve only part of your host names/subdomains that breaks DNS.

Long story short: set up full, A and AAAA records on each DNS server.

Comment: can you elaborate ?